# unixODBC Freetds PHP Problem

Tags: php, sql-server, unix

I am using Debian. I have unixODBC installed as well as FreeTDS. I am using PHP

I have read several How-Tos and am stuck on a problem.

I tested FreeTDS by using tsql and it works.

I tested unixODBC by using isql and it works.

When I created a script in PHP and tried to access a database I get the following errors.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

I have found multiple php.ini files. Which is the one that Apache2 uses? Is there something in there that needs to be set.

Is there some setting that I missed seting that was not in the How-Tos?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is usually a php.ini file for cli and apache2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to provide environment variables to point to the location of your ODBC configuration files:

```
<?php
putenv("FREETDSCONF=/etc/freetds/freetds.conf");
putenv("ODBCSYSINI=/etc/odbcinst.ini");
putenv("ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini");
```

This works for me to connect to several ODBC databases. (Your config files might be somewhere else)

Comment: Hi -
These variables might be needed.  But the immediate problem is "Call to undefined function odbc_connect()".

Sanmai is correct - the OP first needs to install php5-mssql and/or php5-odbc.

Comment: @shrikant-soni stated that he did install those in his comment, I'm assuming he tried that and it did not work, perhaps changing his error message???

Comment: Perhaps he did not restart Apache after the installation.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to install `php5-mssql` and/or `php5-odbc`.
   I'd recommend you to install both just for sure.
2. Files from `/etc/php5/conf.d/` and `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` used to store PHP configuration options in Debian.